# Passing HTML value into JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked already.

However, when I follow the answer given to that question it doesn't work.

This is my JS function and the relevant HTML

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
}
```

```html
 <input class="textbox" type="number" id="number"> 
    <button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById("number").value)" class="Button" >Submit</button>
      <p id="submit"></p>
      <script type ="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: use `onclick="myFunction()"` and access the desired elements inside your function using their ids.

Comment: When you click a `submit` button then your form is submitted **immediately** and no script can run after `submit` event. All tricks with the current page are possible when you use AJAX that is stays on the page while the request is processing *asynchronously*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely none of the answers recommended separating the HTML and JavaScript, so that's what I'll do. It's considered a best practice to not inline JS in your HTML.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('number').value);
  document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
}
```

```html
<input class="textbox" type="number" id="number">
<button class="Button">Submit</button>
<p id="submit"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Get the value insert the function.... It will display your desire output....

```js
function myFunction() {
var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
}
```

```html
<input class="textbox" type="number" id="number"> 
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="Button" >Submit</button>
      <p id="submit"></p>
      <script type ="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought, You used inside double quote("), using double quote("). So Please change double quote inside single quote(') or single quote inside double quote("). **More over button default type is submit**...

**Change following**

```
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById("number").value)" class="Button" >Submit</button>
```

**Into**

```
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('number').value)" class="Button" >Submit</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick='myFunction(document.getElementById("number").value)' class="Button" >Submit</button>
```

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
}
```

Into

```
function myFunction(num) {
      var n = num;//Get the number into your javascript function
      document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
}
```

```html
<input class="textbox" type="number" id="number"> 
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('number').value)" class="Button" type="button" >Submit</button>
  <p id="submit"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(num){
      var n = num;
      
      console.log(n);
      
      document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
    }
  
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you i change it to all choice but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please try this <button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('number').value)" class="Button"  type="button">Submit</button>

Comment: now it work when i put my function in my index.html
but still doesn't work when i put it in index.js
but anyway Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like the earlier answer, you need to use single quote around 'number'.  Another thing, you need to add parameter val in the myFunction(val) in the index.js.

```
function myFunction(val) {
    document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
    console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default type of the `button` element is `submit` (and it is ok; the data will be submitted to the server). If something should be done before submission then it could be processed like this.

```js
function myFunction(element, evn) { //here you can rename parameters
  //evn is click event, element is the button clicked
  evn.preventDefault(); //don't submit form at this moment
  document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
  //now it is safe to submit the form
  //setTimeout is for demonstration purpose
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.form.submit();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!-- form tag supposed to be open -->
<form method="get" action=".">
  <input class="textbox" type="number" id="number" name="numData">
  <!--name attr is required to send data to the server -->
  <!-- note the arguments sent to the function.
Don't change them -->
  <button onclick="myFunction(this,event)" class="Button">Submit</button>
  <!-- form tag may be closed here or later -->
</form>
<p id="submit"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```