# Passing HTML value to embedded script

Tags: javascript, java, html

So I have a HTML file with an embedded script. A Java application sends a value to this HTML file. Now I wonder how to pass this value from the HTML down to the script. Is this even possible?

Here is the simplified HTML file with my approach:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="test">
        [VALUE_FROM_BACKEND] // prints "let valueFromBackend = 1234"
     </div>

  <script>    
    console.log(document.getElementById('test').value);
    // should return: let valueFromBackend = 1234;
    // actually returns: undefined
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I can't pass the value from the Java application directly to the script. I got the above approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384766/passing-html-value-into-javascript-function), but this doesn't work. 
Other solutions only focus on getting values from remote HTML pages, declaring the HTML files's source in the script tag. But since it is an embedded script here, this also seems not to work.

Does anyone know how to deal with the situation? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `input`s have a value, `div`s do not. You could use `.textContent` to access the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only HTML `input` elements have a `value` in javascript. A `div` cannot have a `value`, which is why your code returns `undefined`.

To access the text inside a regular HTML element, such as a `div`, use `element.innerText` instead.

Here is a working code snippet you can try out:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').innerText);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  let valueFromBackend = 1234
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get value of a div element, so the syntax is:
`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML`

Remember that `getElementById().value` works for input and use `getElementById().innerHTML` for elements like div